# icon attribute in Polymer <google-map-marker> not working

Tags: google-maps, polymer

In the repeated (dom-repeat) section, default red markers appear instead of the bus icon.

The img tag inside the second google-map-marker tag works fine (icon appears on click).

```
<google-map latitude="45.559" longitude="-122.65" version="3.exp" zoom="12">

  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[marker_data]]">
    <google-map-marker icon="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/bus.png"
                       latitude=[[item.lat]] longitude=[[item.lon]]  title=[[item.text]]>
    </google-map-marker>
  </template>

  <google-map-marker icon="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/bus.png"
                       latitude=45.54843 longitude=-123.60  title="arrggghhhh!!!!!">
    <img src="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/bus.png">
  </google-map-marker>

</google-map>
```

[screen shot showing red default markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3bQT.png)

Comment: Is it getting downloaded?

Comment: The img tag tag with the same icon is working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `type`of the property. If you check the [documentations](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/elements/google-map-marker#property-icon) they have changed the property type to `Object` instead of `String`. This means that the value has to be in `JSON` format.

Something like this should work.

```
<google-map-marker icon='"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/bus.png"' latitude=[[item.lat]] longitude=[[item.lon]]  title=[[item.text]]>
</google-map-marker>
```

**Notice the `icon` attribute is using both single and double quotes.**

Even i'm not sure how is this interpreted as `JSON` but it seems to work.

[Here's](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/issues/405) the link to Github issue where solution has been posted.